# Not able to save user name and password in browser

Tags: javascript, extjs

Currently am working on a website which is developed in Ext JS,  we need to populate the password when user name is selected using the autocomplete, is there any way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As long as I "know" a username I would be able to login as that user? Then why passwords at all? O.o

Comment: i think am not exactly with my point, in many sites when we are entering any user name we will be getting the info about the users who were logged in earlier, if the pass word is saved in the browser password will be populated automatically when email is selected, in my case am not able to save the password

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can try localStorage or indexDB to save username and password;
after select username,search it in localStorage or indexDB and populate the password;

`localStorage.setItem( 'users', JSON.stringify( [{username: "some name", password:"pwd"}]) );
localStorage.getItem( 'users' )`

Comment: if you use loaclStorage then you need to clear on particular time because localStorage only clear when user manually clear history